# If excess sodium is bad for humans, why don't our bodies just remove it?

Tags: human-biology, diet, salt

This is one of those questions where I realized two everyday facts don't connect for me. Excessive sodium in the diet is supposed to be bad for us. But surely our bodies have mechanisms for getting rid of excess sodium. (I don't know the details, but I know enough about neurons to know that our cells can move sodium when they need to.) Why don't our bodies just keep our sodium levels at a healthy level?

Comment: Are you talking about the long or short term effects of excess sodium?

Comment: I was thinking about blood pressure and stuff like that, but if the answer would be different for different conditions, that would be interesting too.

Comment: Because evolution doesn't care about what's good or bad, just about what lets organisms pass on their genes.  The bad effects of things like high blood pressure usually don't show up until long after most people have done their gene-passing.